# How to upload client files directly from express to minio ? ( nodejs )

Tags: node.js, express, multer, minio, multer-s3

im using express framework and i want to have a middleware to be able to upload files directly from clients to minio s3, how is that possible ?

i tried using multer-s3 package but it gave me error, here is the opened issue on multer-s3's github:

https://github.com/anacronw/multer-s3/issues/190

i also tied to use other packages like multer-minio-storage but it gave me error, here is the opened issue on multer-minio-storage's github:

https://github.com/hoangnguyen1247/multer-minio-storage/issues/20

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.